# How can I get a divider line between the AutoCompleteTextView and the suggestions dropdown?

Tags: android, autocomplete

I would like to put a divider line or shadow between the `AutoCompleteTextView` and the suggestions dropdown, pretty close to what it is done on Chrome. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this may be a good solution.

You just have to add a new view, with a "divider" style, as shown in the code below, and set the property *dropDownAnchor* equals to the id of the divider.

This is an example of the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/textAutocomplete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:dropDownAnchor="@+id/dropdownDivider"
        android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
        android:popupBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="@string/type_words" />

    <View
        android:id="@id/dropdownDivider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark"/>

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

The result image of this code is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyyWz.png).